# workaround for hv length units

Tags: css

I'm using `top: 50vh` to always position my image in the center of the screen regardless of the screen size. Now I've discovered that some old webkit browsers do not support this type of length unix. What is the best workaround?

Here is my setup:

```
.icon-preloader-xs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-image: url('../resources/img/icon-preloader-xs.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 50hv;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this method that is not based on `hv` unit. Image is assumed to be 100px by 100px square.

You can also use percentages or other relative values instead of pixels. You can always calculate this if you are using Sass, or just use Javascript to set the margins dynamically.

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -50px;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4zy63m9k/2/

Comment: This would position my image in the center of the entire page, I need it positioned in the center of the screen. Or wouldn't it?

Comment: If you want to use the device viewport, then you could use the viewport metatag to scale the page correctly. This assumes that your container is 100% of the (browser/device) viewport.

You could then use percentage units for the image itself and not use the px I have used here.

Can you give me an example, so I can check your case and propose a more specific workaround?

Comment: updated my answer, also modified your solution to show the problem I'm talking about http://jsfiddle.net/n4unruv8/

Comment: Ok. Could this be a solution? Perhaps in combination with a meta viewport tag? http://jsfiddle.net/n4unruv8/1/ and http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/